# Библиотека Javassist - Ошибка при создании модифицированного .class

Tags: java, jar

Я декомпилировал `.apk` с помощью `Apktool`, `classes.dex` с помощью `dex2jar` и открыл `jar` для просмотра `java` кода в `jd-gui`. Мне нужно вставить свой код в начало метода одного класса. Использую `javassist`. Создал программу в `.java` файле, пытаюсь его скомпилировать

```
javac -cp ./javassist.jar Hook.java
```

Получаю файлик `Hook.class`, в итоге в одной папке лежат:

- javassist.jar
- android.jar (из Android SDK)
- SecretCode.class (из декомпилированного dex2jar.jar)
- Полученный Hook.class

В SecretCode.class есть метод getPassword(), в который передаются данные паролей, которые нужны для активации Автозагрузки USB. Мне нужно вставить код, который будет выводить пароли в Toast сообщении. Он должен расположиться в самом начале метода getPassword(). 
Итак, вот мой Hook.java с кодом...

```
import javassist.*;
import java.util.logging.*;
import java.io.IOException;
public class Hook
{
public void addHook(String targetClass, String targetMethod)
    throws NotFoundException, CannotCompileException, IOException
{
    Logger logger = Logger.getLogger("Javassist");
    final String targetFolder = "./modified/";

    try
    {
        final ClassPool pool = ClassPool.getDefault();
        pool.appendClassPath(new LoaderClassPath(getClass().getClassLoader()));
        pool.appendClassPath("./android.jar");
        final CtClass compiledClass = pool.get(targetClass);
        final CtMethod method = compiledClass.getDeclaredMethod(targetMethod);
        method.insertBefore("Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), $1 + $2, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();");
        compiledClass.writeFile(targetFolder);
        logger.info(targetClass + "." + targetMethod + " has been modified and saved under " + targetFolder);
    }
    catch (NotFoundException e)
    {
        logger.warning("Failed to find the target class to modify " + targetClass);
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args)
    throws Exception
{
    final String targetClass = "com.android.customsettings.SecredCode";
    final String targetMethod = "getPassword";

    new Hook().addHook(targetClass, targetMethod);
}
}
```

Теперь я должен написать команду, которая по сути вставит код для всплывающего Toast сообщения в начало метода `getPassword()` класса `SecretCode.class`:

```
java -cp .;javassist.jar;android.jar Hook
```

Команда не срабатывает, дело в методе **insertBefore()** который вставляет мой код, *not such class Toast* пишет мне командная строка, я не пойму в чем проблема? Я разве неправильно написал код для Toast?

Расскажите, что не так в `Hook.java`, или может я что-то не так делаю? И еще - как сработает эта команда?
P.S Класс `SecretCode.class` я не вынул из jar архива, я просто создал его, а код скопировал с jd-gui

Comment: По-моему вопрос нужно задать "Как из java-class" собрать dex"

Comment: В jar собирает утилита jar.exe. Описание на неё достаточно хорошее.

Comment: @nick_n_a, вовсе нет :D мне не нужен .jar, я остановился на этапе внедрения кода из Hook.java в SecretCode.class. Самое интересное, что тестовый java (который в самом javassist) отлично запускается. в чем дело с моим Hook.java не пойму. Что-то не так с методом addHook()...

Comment: Исключение-то какое? Строка, которую вы привели, выводится вашим же кодом. Этого недостаточно для диагностики.

Comment: @Pavel Mayorov, а больше ничего и нет) Выбрасывается catch из-за ошибки в try...

Comment: @СергейГрушин вам в catch попадает исключение. *Что в нем?!* Где системное сообщение об ошибке (не ваше!), где тректрейс?

Comment: @PavelMayorov, сам понял ошибку и продвинулся дальше, вопрос изменил, прочитайте пожалуйста

Comment: @PavelMayorov  и кстати - у меня модифицированный SecretCode не запускается в JD-GUI, пишет INTERNAL ERROR, почему так? :(

Comment: Минуточку! Вы получили этот код из apk? Тоесть из приложения для андроида, так? И при этом компилить пытаетесь через обычную java? Дык может там запрашиваются методы чисто для андроида. Может в этом и проблема?

Comment: Бросил javassist, успешно работаю в smali